# Creating a ListBox that holds multiple datagrids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to make a search application using a wpf and entity framework following mvvm design patterns. When you search for someone, I want the ListBox to dynamically hold as many datagrids, as the search shows up. The datagrid will hold information such as first and last name, as well as a profile picture. I am kind of new to wpfs and c# in general, but I was thinking that the datagrid with all its information would be its own xaml. Then somehow I could add that xaml to the listbox as many times as I needed to(depending on the number of search results). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Easy one: [ListBox.ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The DataGrid XAML goes in the item template.

The search results go in an ObservableCollection of your search result class. That collection will be a member of your viewmodel, and in XAML you'll bind the collection to ListBox.ItemsSource.

The ListBox will instantiate the ItemTemplate once for each item in the search results collection.

Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your viewmodel, and raise PropertyChanged when you replace the collection with a new one. Changes to the collection's contents aren't your problem: use an ObservableCollection and it'll raise its own notifications for adds and removes. The ListBox will subscribe to those notifications without being asked.